# Error in this query : how to solve it ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a Oracle query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE 
        CODE='AMB01'
        AND MyHour BETWEEN 
            TO_DATE('11/01/2018 16:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND
            TO_DATE('11/01/2018 16:30:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

It return an error :

```
Month not valid
```

Myhour is a String field.

What can be the error ?

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you storing DATE values in a `VARCHAR` column? You need to fix your table design, then this query will work just fine.

Comment: I'm not storing as a varchar.. the truth is that is a complex query and myHour is a string field (composed from others fields).

Comment: There is no "string" data type in Oracle - it's called VARCHAR. The **correct** fix to your problem is to stop storing date values in a VARCHAR ("string") column and store them in a `DATE` column. The reason for your problem is, that this VARCHAR column contains "strings" that can't be converted to a DATE

Comment: To workaround your design flaw, use `to_date(myhour, '....')` and supply the correct format mask for the values stored in that column.

Comment: I'm not storing a Varchar.. and i'm trying to supply the correct format mask

Comment: Or more likely your constructed `MyHour` string is in a format that doesn't match your NLS settings, since you're relying on inplicit conversion. Why aren't you explicitly converting `MyHour` to a date for the comparison? (Not disagreeing that it should be a date already...)

Comment: So what data type **is** the column `Myhour`? (again there is no "string" data type in Oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
You need to convert MyHour, not between part.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE 
        CODE='AMB01'
        AND TO_DATE(MyHour, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN 
           '11-01-2018 16:00:00' AND
           '11-01-2018 16:30:00'
```

Comment: Isn't that what they are already doing, with a different valid format, but with a time component too - which you are ignoring?

Comment: I didnt understand the question properly. I edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

if `MyHour` type is different , Set column type as `Date`

> ```
> UPDATE_DATETIME           DATE
> ```

```
 SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE   MyHour BETWEEN 
  TO_DATE('11/01/2018 16:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND
  TO_DATE('11/01/2018 16:30:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```